# Is there a nexus3 single configuration file like nexus.xml in nexus2?

Tags: nexus3

using Nexus2 we have stored the nexus.xml with all the configuration settings in our git repo so we can always recreate our nexus from scratch. With nexus3 the structures seems changed and I can't find if there is a similar xml file that holds the repositories and other configuration settings so I could add this file to our git repo. When I have such a file I could create a docker image that contains this config so no configuration time is necessary in the future.

regards

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no single file for Nexus Repository Manager 3 that contains config. A lot is stored inside OrientDB, and this is by design. In our 3.2 release, there will be a database export function that will likely be of good use for you. This will create a GZIP'd json file (probably not the best thing to check into git), but you can keep it somewhere for recovery purposes.

Another thing that might be of use is to use something like Chef to provision Repository Manager instances. A cool community member and others have been collaborating on this: https://github.com/dhoer/chef-nexus3 , which may be of use to you.